# Fondo con mas transparencia y mas azul en css

Tags: css, html5, fondo

Hola he probado muchas cosas para que se vea un fondo con un terminacion mas azul y con un poco de transparencia

```
.sect {
  background-image: url(imgblog/cover.jpg) ;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 100 , 0.5);
  opacity: .9;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 100px;
  border-radius: 15px;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo dos ejemplos para crear un `overlay`.

La idea es que envuelvas tu imagen dentro de un `div` y a este `div` le aplicas las propiedades de color y transparencia.

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 100, 0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
</div>
```

Con esta opción tienes un `div` separado que se superpone a la imagen y a este le aplicas las propiedades:

```css
.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 0;
}

.img-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 100 , 0.5);
}

.img-wrapper img {width: 200px;}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <div class="img-overlay"></div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
</div>
```

Cambia los tamaños para que se ajusten a tu necesidad.